# Visual Studio Online Build treats git output as errors

Tags: azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, azure-devops, f#-fake, kudu

My build in Visual Studio Online tries to deploy my Azure web site via [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu). The script works fine, and deployment goes through, but VSO treats git output as errors for some reason, and declares the whole build failed. Take a look at the screenshot below.

Some details:

1. This is a "new scripted" build, not a XAML-defined one.
2. Build definition has just one step, which executes a PowerShell script, which runs [F# FAKE](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/) (not sure if this is relevant).
3. When I run the same script on my local machine, I don't see any "strange" output, including the `[K` at the end of each line.
4. After running on my local, `$LastExitCode` is zero.
5. I very much would like to keep the build to one step, so I can continue leveraging the power of FAKE.

[image]

Comment: Odd. Have you tried printing `$LastExitCode` from the script to see if it's 0 when running under VSO build?

Comment: In which script? Do you mean in the PowerShell script right after executing FAKE?

Comment: Tried it just now. At the very end of my PowerShell script, the `$LastExitCode` is zero. It seems that VSO makes the judgement purely based on the text output.

Comment: Really not sure what VSO is doing here. It may be that some of the output is sent to stderr instead of stdout, and they treat this as an error condition regardless of the exit code. Though that would be very questionable behavior, and it's only a wild guess. I work on the Kudu part, and I'm not very familiar with what's happening on the VSO part that's calling it.

Comment: Does this only occur when run git pull and push command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git outputs its content to the error stream which Visual Studio Team Services interprets as error.

You need to redirect Gits output in your script like this to make it working:

`git pull 2>&1 | Write-Host`

Comment: Sorry for being so long, got distracted with other stuff. Yes, this is the answer, just redirecting stderr to stdout solved it.