# Hiding response from remote tfs-git during GIT Push to TFS-GIT

Tags: git, github, tfs, azure-devops, git-push

I'm trying to sync files present in git-hub repository(used by remote team) to local git repository in TFS.

For this purpose i'm using following commands:

```
REM Public GIT repository
git remote set-url  origin https://github.com/<user>/<Project>.git
REM Private GIT repository
git remote set-url targettfs  http://LocalServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/<ProjectName>

REM Pull updates from GITHUB
git reset --hard HEAD  
git fetch origin --quiet
git pull origin master --quiet

REM Sync TFS-GIT to local
git init
git reset --hard HEAD  
git fetch targettfs --quiet
git pull targettfs master --quiet
git add .
git commit -m "sync file with github" --quiet

REM Push updates to GIT repository in TFS
git push origin master  --quiet
```

This script doing major task as expected, Problem here is when doing this i'm getting some response is written back in console like below:

[image: GIT push feedback message]

For this i tried --quiet with TFS push, but no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot, TFS Build treats git output as errors. Please check the answer [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301951/visual-studio-online-build-treats-git-output-as-errors):

> Git outputs its content to the error stream which Visual Studio Team
>   Services interprets as error.
>
> You need to redirect Gits output in your script like this to make it
>   working:
>
> `git pull 2>&1 | Write-Host`

Comment: This approach forwards all errors !! but here i just want suppress only those information statements from TFS-GIT starting "remote:". Is there any way?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find other ways to suppress only starting "remote:". How about splitting the command to use git push separately and suppress the error for this command?